# Laravel query builder - using data within row to compare with time in another

Tags: laravel, eloquent, query-builder, laravel-query-builder

I have got this working using a whereRaw as follow:

```
Reports::whereRaw('last_check_datetime < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL `check_schedule_minutes` MINUTE')->get();
```

The table has a number of reports in it, with differing schedule minutes. i.e. I want one report to be checked every 15 mins and another to be checked every 60 mins. If the time in `last_check_datetime` is not older than the number of minutes in `check_schedule_minutes` then the report should not be returned in the collection.

Is there a way to achieve the same thing using a more Eloquent syntax, ideally with Carbon?

Answer (score 1):

Tbh I think what you're doing here is right. The problem is in your question - you're wanting to merge PHP/MySQL syntax, but the data is in MySQL. So without first fetching all records and then doing a check, what you've done is right, and not really avoidable. However, if you really want more eloquent buildery-solution, here:

```
Reports::where('last_check_datetime', '<', DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL `check_schedule_minutes` MINUTE'))->get();
```

Tbh though, I think the whereRaw is neater.

Comment: Thanks for that. I agree - I think its much of the same really. My aim would be to get the Carbon helpers into the query, but it does not seem like this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use eloquent's `whereBetween` method on date columns

`Reports::whereBetween('last_check_datetime', [Carbon::now()->subMinutes($check_schedule_minutes), Carbon::now()])->get();`

Should do the trick for you.

EDIT: I realise this relies on you knowing the `$check_schedule_minutes` value before making the query, where your question is reading `check_schedule_minutes` from the table.
One way to solve this would be to have a predefined standard for `check_schedule_minutes` (15 or 60 mins as you said) then have that value passed into the function performing the query and add that to your conditions:

```php
$check_schedule_minutes = 60;

Reports::whereBetween('last_check_datetime', [Carbon::now()->subMinutes($check_schedule_minutes), Carbon::now()])
->where('check_schedule_minutes', $check_schedule_minutes)
->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for this. The $check_schedule_minutes can actually be anything from 15 mins through to a month, so really I need a way to be able to pull this from each row of the database on the fly